# Combination of Content of Multiple Text files into One Text File line after the other using Python

Tags: python

I have used the following code in combining multiple text file into one,

```
import glob

read_files = glob.glob("*.txt")

with open("result.txt", "wb") as outfile:
       for f in read_files:
           with open(f, "rb") as infile:
               outfile.write(infile.read())
```

the output I receive from the above code is

> 2020-06-22,09:37:39 ,YZ-5534 ,72kmph ,100kmph ,No2020-06-22,09:38:21
> ,CAB-3365 ,79kmph ,100kmph ,No2020-06-22,09:40:42 ,ABC-5432 ,98kmph
> ,100kmph ,No2020-06-22,09:39:41 ,CB-3226 ,117kmph ,100kmph
> ,Yes2020-06-22,09:36:54 ,QX-9904 ,81kmph ,100kmph ,No

how do I introduce line break at the end of the content of each text
file as so

> 2020-06-22,09:37:39 ,YZ-5534 ,72kmph ,100kmph ,No
>
> 2020-06-22,09:38:21,CAB-3365,79kmph,100kmph,No
>
> 2020-06-22,09:40:42,ABC-5432,98kmph,100kmph,No
>
> 2020-06-22,09:39:41,CB-3226,117kmph,100kmph,Yes
>
> 2020-06-22,09:36:54,QX-9904,81kmph,100kmph,No

**In order to get the above as the final result in the joined text file**

I tried the following line of code of the above yet didn't work at all

```
outfile.write(infile.read()+ '\n')
```

Comment: Could you please share a few lines of the files you're trying to combine?

Comment: It's just 1 line in each text file as mentioned below

Comment: 2020-06-22,09:36:54
,QX-9904
,81kmph
,100kmph
,No

Answer (score 0):

Since you're reading from text files, could you give this a shot?

```py
import glob

read_files = glob.glob("*.txt")

with open("result.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "r") as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
            outfile.write("\n")
```

Comment: No, Still doesn't come as per my requirement ... Above code divides the text file by its ',' and afterward, the line space is introduced

Comment: Divided into parts by the comma

Comment: I want the output line by line

Comment: each line should be as

Comment: 2020-06-22,09:36:54
,QX-9904
,81kmph
,100kmph
,No

Comment: 2020-06-22,09:38:21
,CAB-3365
,79kmph
,100kmph
,No

Comment: 2020-06-22,09:40:42
,ABC-5432
,98kmph
,100kmph
,No

Comment: not all together as because my goal to send all above to MYSQL Database

Comment: That's what my program does. Please share a link to say, 2 files on github. I'll update my post with the output

Comment: @Uchiha95 Please provide the corresponding output for the files you upload in a file named `result.txt`.